# CLion freeze when compiles

Tags: c++, windows, clion

I'm trying to run a basic hello world on cLion, but when I run the application it's freeze complete.
Here is a screen capture that you can see the console, and the code.
[image: screen capture from the frozed application]

and here the version that I am using for the compiler, the CMake and the GDB[image: build configuration]

I tried to use cygwin64, but the version they have for the GDB is 7.7x, and is incompatible for cLion, they need 1.8.x

Comment: disable your antivirus

Comment: thanks, that really help, I add the compilation exception to the antivirus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling the antivirus or adding an exception for your program; what happens is that the antivirus thinks your program is a virus because it is an executable that just got created and run.  Avast is particularly notorious for this.